# DOM changes don't execute in interval function

Tags: javascript, dom, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm working on a basic alerting system in javascript that makes a basic circle clock count down and then disappear on a map I'm making.

I have however run into a small snag since I can't figure out why **line 11 and 12** in the code block below (marked by arrows) don't want to do their thing.

```
function createTimer(sysID){
    this.IDstore = sysID;
    this.time = 59;
    var self = this;
    document.getElementById('star'+self.IDstore).style.fill="#FF0000";

    this.timer = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById('Timer'+self.IDstore).setAttribute('d', updateState(self.time));
        self.time-=1;
        if(self.time<=0){
        ->  document.getElementById('Timer'+self.IDstore).style.visibility="hidden";
        ->  document.getElementById('star'+self.IDstore).style.fill="#FFFFFF";
            clearInterval(self.timer);
        }
    },1000);
    this.stopTime=stopTime;
}
```

If I however remove the **clearInterval** or move them out of the if statement they work fine. But simply making them run by themself before the execution of the **clearInterval** like in the next code block does not work.

```
function createTimer(sysID){
    this.IDstore = sysID;
    this.time = 59;
    var self = this;
    document.getElementById('star'+self.IDstore).style.fill="#FF0000";
    this.timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(self.time>=0){
            document.getElementById('Timer'+self.IDstore).setAttribute('d', updateState(self.time));
        }else if(self.time>-2){
            document.getElementById('Timer'+self.IDstore).style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('star'+self.IDstore).style.fill="#FFFFFF";
        }else{
            clearInterval(self.timer);
        }
        self.time-=1;
    },1000);
    this.stopTime=stopTime;
}
```

Would be great to know why and if there is a simple solution.

Comment: The 2nd block of code [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/WJaKS/1/). Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: probably one of these `document.getElementById` return undefined and then accessing a property of undefined throws an error, that stops processing the rest of your function. did you check your browser's debugger console?

Comment: Yep, no error messages at all and both of them triggers my break points in chrome which I take as that they are running just fine. And the clearInterval executes to so it doesn't seem to stop anywhere...

Comment: it even trigger my dom break points but it still doesn't change the actual look of the objects...